# Как отследить событие switch c помощью jquery?

Tags: jquery

есть switch и хочу на него поставеть слушатель событий дествия с помощью jquery 
но он не сработал... почему ?
вот `html`

```
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

вот css

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

а вот и jquery :

```
 $('.switch').change(function(){
    if(switch==true)
{alert('2')
}else{alert('d')}
})
```

Comment: а что вы проверяете в `if( switch == true)`, что за переменная `switch` у вас?

Comment: сам по себе класс `.switch` не имеет события `change`. Такое событие может быть у `.switch input`

Comment: хмммм и как мне быть?как провереть нажат ли свитч или нет

Comment: быть так как написано в моем ответе ;)

Comment: @teran ахахах товарищ вы убили меня своим комментом )))ахахах спасибо за настроение и ответ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно заменить код jQuery:

```
$('.switch input').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert('on')
    }
    else {
        alert('off');
    }
});
```

`label` - это метка всего лишь. Состояние переключателя отражается в элементе `input`.

Работающий код [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so/622966.html).

Comment: Здравствуй дорогой Товарищ.Спасибо что помогли мне найти с решением ответа!

Comment: Пожалуйста ) обращайтесь еще...

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь присоединить обработчик события `change` к элементу класса `switch`. Однако такое событие генерирует вложенный элемент `input` с типом `checkbox`.
Поэтому код следует переписать соответствующим образом:

```js
$(".switch input").change(function(){
    $("#result").text( $(this).prop('checked') ? "ON" : "OFF" );
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
<span id="result"></span>
```